# Use of deps.json file in .NET 6 since getting missing deps.json file

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, runtime-error, .net-6.0, serilog

I have a WPF application. That application depends on a configuration file which contains 2 sections of configurations - one for the app, and one for logging.

My issue is for logging use case. I have created a separate nuget package where I am adding serilog for the project. From my json I am extracting the serilog section into an `IConfiguration` object and then using one of the Serilog functions to read the configuration from that `IConfiguration` object. But in that nuget code I am getting an error "deps.json file missing".

JSON file:

```
{
   "AppConfiguration":{
   },
   "LogConfiguration":{
      "Serilog":{
         "MinimumLevel":"Debug",
         "Enrich":[ "FromLogContext" ]
      }
   }
}
```

Then in my consumer or the WPF application that is going to use my Serilog nuget package I have written the below logic to get log configuration for serilog

```
// ConfigurationManager class

var appConfiguration = new AppConfiguration();
configuration.GetSection("AppConfiguration").Bind(appConfiguration);

IConfiguration logConfiguration = configuration.GetSection("LogConfiguration");
```

I am sending `logConfiguration` as a param to nuget to create and add serilog for the application.

```
// Nuget method to configure serilog for app
// Here getting deps.json file missing Error

public static ILoggingBuilder AddAppSerilog(
        this ILoggingBuilder builder,
        IConfiguration logConfiguration,
        string outputTemplate = DefaultOutputTemplate,
        IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
{
    var seriLog = new LoggerConfiguration() ------Error
            .ReadFrom
            .Configuration(logConfiguration)
            .Enrich
            .FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo
            .MySink(outputTemplate, formatProvider)
            .CreateLogger();

    builder.AddSerilog(seriLog);

    return builder;
}
```

This code will be called in the WPF application when configuring services which will call the serilog nuget method to configure it.

```
services
    .AddSingleton<IConfigurationManager, ConfigurationManager>()
    .AddLogging(configure =>
    {
        var configuration = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ConfigurationManager>();
        configure.AddAppSerilog(configuration.LogConfiguration);
    });
```

What is the use of that `deps.json` file? And how it is impacting my use case or example as explained since `deps.json` is missing?